# A replacement for a temporary table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

within a stored procedure/code block (SP/CB), I need a way to store intermediate results from a query (I'm using Oracle 11g). The idea is that I select some data, store them (in a variable), and later in my SP/CB I use them in other queries. And don't want to create any schema-level object for that (types, and even less so -- tables).

In MS SQL a temporary table would do just fine, but in Oracle it is not an option since in Oracle temporary table are created at schema-level. Object and collection would do, but I have to create object types at schema level, too. Next, there the option of 'nested tables':

```
DECLARE
   TYPE MyRowType   IS RECORD (<some fields here>);
   TYPE MyTableType IS TABLE OF MyRowType;
   myTable          MyTableType;
```

I can select whatever data I need into myTable via BULK COLLECT INTO, but want I fail to achieve is to SELECT data from myTable.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE <some constraint>
```

This fails with the message that there is no such table 'myTable '. The other variant:

```
SELECT * FROM table(myTable) WHERE <some constraint>
```

-- also fails (it says that myTable is not a nested table).

The reason why I can't use the WITH clause is that queries where I'd need the data from myTable are scattered all over the SP. The only option I can think of is to create MyTableType (something like CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE OF MyRowType), but that would create an object at DB scheme level.

So basically, can someone point me to a workaround, so that I would not have to create any permanent objects and manage with locally defined types and objects?

Comment: In order to do a `select` you will need a database object.

Comment: In Oracle 12c it is possible to use `SELECT * FROM table(myTable)` without prior creation the TYPE in DB Schema.

Comment: And why can't you create the temporary table? You apparently can already run a `CREATE PROCEDURE` (which is create at "schema level") so why can't you run a `create temporary table`? What prevents you from creating more "schema level" objects? Your tables are also created at "schema level"...

Comment: A global temp table maybe your answer. Maintaining lines of code because you think you cannot use that is already provided by Oracle is wrong, inefficient and usually become a nightmare for the company.

Comment: why not use in this case "Pipelined and Parallel Table Functions" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipelined function to do this.  For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package TEST_PKG AS
    TYPE t_num_tab IS TABLE OF number;
    num_tab t_num_tab;

    function get_nums(i_cnt in number) return t_num_tab pipelined;

    procedure run_test;

    procedure init_num_tab;

END;
```

And the body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body TEST_PKG AS

    FUNCTION get_nums(i_cnt in number) 
    return t_num_tab pipelined IS
        l_cnt number := 0;
    BEGIN
        if (num_tab.count = 0) then
            return;
        end if;
        for i in num_tab.first .. num_tab.last
        loop
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
            if (l_cnt > i_cnt) then
                return;
            end if;
            pipe row(i);
        end loop;
    END;

    PROCEDURE run_test IS
        l_my_local_num_tab  t_num_tab;
    BEGIN

        select * 
        bulk collect into l_my_local_num_tab
        from table (get_nums(5));

        for i in 1 .. l_my_local_num_tab.count
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line('Value is: ' || i);
        end loop;

    END run_test;


    PROCEDURE init_num_tab IS
    BEGIN
      select level
      bulk collect into num_tab
      from dual
      connect by level <= 10;
    END init_num_tab;

    -- INIT tables
    BEGIN
       init_num_tab;
END;
```

The procedure run_test shows the using it in the package.  Outside of the package would be similar:

```
select * from table(test_pkg.get_nums(5));
```

Output:

```
COLUMN_VALUE
1
2
3
4
5
```